# SSMS SQL: CHR(9) being replaced by a space when copying and pasting Query Result to Notepad- is there a setting?

Tags: sql, tabs, ssms, notepad

I'm running a query inside a an SP to build a line of text eg:

```sql
SELECT 'Heading1' + CHAR(9) + 'Heading2' + CHAR(9) + 'Heading3' AS TextLine
UNION
SELECT String1 + CHAR(9) + String2 + CHAR(9) + String3 AS TextLine
FROM SourceTable etc etc
```

The results go to a grid, however, when I copy and paste the results from the results grid and paste them into Notepad the TABS are converted to a single space.

I can correct this behavior by sending the results to text rather than a grid, however, a colleague gets the tabs even when the results go to a grid so we must have different settings somewhere.  Any idea what the setting may be as I cant see anything obvious in the Query->Query Options menu.

Thanks in advance for any help :-)

Comment: Do you have the "Retain CR/LF on copy or Save" setting switched on? I would suggest not.

Comment: It was already set to that setting and I have restarted SSMS many times since creating query.